# Is it possible to make find() and findOne() method return only schema fields

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I searched an option inside documentation and on the net but I didn't find any answer, so let's ask the question.

Why by running the following code :

```
var accountSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id :            { type:Number, unique:true },
    login :         { type:String, unique:true, index:true },
    password :      String,
    usedBySession : String
});
var account = mongoose.model('Account', accountSchema);

account.findOne({id:1}).exec()
    .then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    },function(err){
        throw err;
    });
```

I get all fields (with `_id`) instead only my schema fields ? Server response is below.

```
{"__v":0,"_id":"538deecb900f64d43163759a","id":1,"login":"dbyzero","password":"f71dbe52612345678907ab494817525c6"}
```

What is the cleanest way to clean the response if no option exists ?

Comment: If you don't specify _id field in your Schema mongoose adds it automatically, if you don't need this field you can disable it, mongoose.Schema({....}, {_id: false});

Comment: Look like a nice approch !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude unnecessary fields in the following way:

```
account.findOne({id: 1}, '-_id -__v -password') // exclude _id, __v, password fields
    .exec()
    .then(success, failure);
```

[More info](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select)

or use `select` option in Schema

```
var yourSchema = new Schema({
   secure: {
       type: String,
       select: false // 'secure' field will not be selected by default
   },
   public: String
});
```

[More info](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-select)

Comment: Yes I saw this method. But if I add a new field in my schema (oldPassword ?) . I have to think about remove it from all my queries... not really robust..

Comment: then you can define schema method that will clean your document from unneccessary or secure fields

Comment: And what about the select option on fields ?  `password :      {type:String,select:false}` look nice !

Comment: Wow! This is certainly the most correct way to achieve your goals! Updated answer